# In cakephp3 how do I create a REST API where output types can be defined as either JSON or XML?

Tags: php, api, rest, routes, cakephp-3.0

New to cake and struggling with the basics. I want to create an API which essentially gives database access to users.

So, I want something like the following for my routes:

-/myAPI/view/viewname.xml
 -/myAPI/view/viewname.json

Essentially, these urls will return all data in the view defined in either xml or JSON.

Here is an example of a route I have created for a View:

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Homepage', 'action' => 'index']);
});

Router::scope('/myAPI', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'XML']);
    $routes->resources( 'View',
            ['only' => ['view'],
            'id'=>'[0-9a-zA-Z]+']);
});

Plugin::routes();
```

When I navigate to /myAPI/view/name.xml I get:

```
<response>
<message>Invalid input.</message>
<url>/myAPI/View/name.xml</url>
<code>500</code>
</response>
```

Here is my view method in the controller:

```
public function view($viewname)
{
$response = array('foo' => 'bar');

$this->set('response', $response);
$this->set('_serialize', 'response');
}
```

It works with .json however but not with .xml. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your post to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the json response is working try the following

```
Router::scope('/myAPI', function ($routes) {
$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
});
```

Instead of 'XML'

I also recommend you [this](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/) tutorial.

EDIT:

I just implemented in the controller

```
public function view($viewname)
{
    $response = array('foo' => 'bar');
    $this->set('response', $response);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'response');
}
```

In routes.php

```
Router::scope('/myAPI', function ($routes) {
$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
});
```

Using this URL:

```
myAPI/controllername/view/name.xml
```

I get a succesful response.

Check your URL I believe you are missing the controller name.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this earlier but I still get the Invalid Input response when using XML only. JSON is fine.

Comment: Hi, what is the name of the controller you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure why it didn't work before but I was doing some different re-factoring and when I checked it again it worked. Marked your answer as correct as it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it has started working now. Probably some caching issue.

I have noticed that for XML to work you do need to define a key in the set response line.

Example:

```
$this->set('response', array('RESPONSE' => $someArrayData));
```

Without this the XML parser fails. Only when I removed the example and put in my formatted array did it work although I am still not sure why it didn't work with the basic example.